# How do I reference this variable?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

The following will grab a result from a mysql line (with about 25 entries of data in an array)

```
$data['records'] = $this->testingsearch->getMessages($id);
```

If I call it in a View after passing `$data`, I would call it like this (and this works just fine):

```
foreach ($records as $row) {
$row->ModelName;
}
```

If I wanted to reference that same variable in the controller, how would I do so?

I've tried the following:
`$data['records']->ModelName` and `$data['records']['ModelName']`. Neither actually pull the value.

Comment: Use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to notice it is a [multidimensional array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

Comment: Your $data['records'] is an array, so grab $data['records'][0]->Modelname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
echo $data['records'][0]->ModelName;
```